# Importing SWF as sprite to gamemaker

Tags: game-maker

with the new gamemaker version we are able to import swf with vector images that allow us to scale to any screen. But i am having problem importing the files from Illustrator and Flash. I have tried all the configuration and it wont work....

have any 1 tried this yet? What configurations did you use?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Download the swf to gif converter [here](http://en.kioskea.net/download/download-8564-swf-to-gif-converter).

And then import the gif image.
So, you can use it as an animation too.

Answer (score 0):

Export as jpeg in flash then import that image to gamemaker.